# Label size, panel size changes when I close and open the designer file

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-mobile

This might sound crazy but couldn't figure out why this has been happening.
I'm developing app on windows mobile 6. I use win forms for UI. Consider a form I created in  sample1.cs, with some labels and text boxes on panel. And neatly adjust size and location.

When I close the sample.cs designer file from visual studio and reopen it, some how I get different values for lable size or textbox size, or panel size. How many times I ever change, finally if I close and re-open it, all the labels have different size - all formatting is gone :(

Any idea about what has been happening, this is really frustrating... :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to bizarre world of Windows Mobile :) Had exactly the same problem and never found a solution. In some instances VS even decided to delete controls(!) on save/reload. Ultimately frustration got me into dropping visual designer altogether and doing everything by hand.

Comment: Oh boy, don't scare me, this prod's release date is very soon :(

Comment: no answers? :(

really scared to open a form now :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your Form_Show event, add code to set your controls to the size you need them to be.

The easiest way to do this, from withing VS2008, is to have both the GUI and the code windows open, go to the menu up top in VS, and select Window > New Vertical Tab Group. Select one of your controls in the GUI, make note of that control's Size and Location in the Properties window, then write that in the Form_Show event.

[image]

Comment: Since there is no better way of fixing this, marking this as final answer. thanks jp2code.

Comment: And this way of fixing things, will not work for all models. For ex: it doesn't work for LG-verizon model, funny :)